# Is it ok to use React Navigation Stack/Drawer in your app when its dependency (@react-native-community/masked-view) does not have a license file?

Tags: mit, license, dependencies

I would like to use React Navigation in my React Native app which I would like to distribute in the Google Play Store.  Both Stack and Drawer implementations of React Navigation have MIT licenses with the corresponding license files so I may acknowledge the use of them but one of there dependencies (@react-native-community/masked-view) says it has a MIT license but does not have a license file so I am worried to use it meaning I cant use React Navigation Stack/Drawer.  @react-native-community/masked-view looks like a popular library and many people are using it so I'm wondering if its safe for me to use React Navigation Stack/Drawer even though one of the dependencies has no license file but acknowledges it has an MIT license.  I'm just worried about installing the library then getting in trouble down the line from the creators.

Comment: Did you ask at the project homepage or repository itself to clarify?

Comment: If it doesn't have a licence file, how do you know it's distributed under an MIT licence?  That's not supposed to be a trick question, by the way: if you have good reason to believe that the software is being conveyed to you under the terms of the MIT licence, the absence of a file named `./LICENSE` is immaterial.

Comment: the package.json file in the repo which defines the npm visible info states that the project is under MIT.

Comment: Well the license file includes the copyright notice and permission notice which must be included with the users software.  This is found within the MIT license file.  So you would need this file if you want to use the library.

Comment: strictly speaking no special form is required for a license to be valid; well-established means to communicate the license clearly make this easier - like a license file with copyright notice. However if that is not the case, then in case of doubt, and if the validity of the license is contested, it must be proven in court you received it unser the license under which you make use of the software.